# Repeating only a portion of a texture in OpenGL ES?

Tags: opengl-es, texture-mapping, tiling

I know it's possible to repeat an entire texture by setting the wrap mode to GL_REPEAT, but is it somehow possible to repeat only a subregion of the texture? For example, when the texture is part of an atlas.

I'm targetting OpenGL ES 1.x, so shaders are out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatelly, it is not possible. The only thing you can do it to repeat side pixels (if the image is at the edge of a texture altals).

If you need tiling – probably the only solution here is generate is with geometry. Otherwise, just go with a separate texture.